# C# как ограничить доступ к колекции

Tags: c#, mvvm

У меня есть коллекция записей и мне нужно добавить в нее новую, уникальную (поиск по всех записях), запись. Новую запись добавляем в отдельном окне, новая view model, вопрос насколько допустимо давать доступ ко всей колекции в ету vm и как можно его ограничить? т.е. в идеале должно быть разрешено только добавление и проверка на уникальность, запрещено удалять, изменять другие и т.д.

Comment: Напишите свой класс, пусть он принимает коллекцию в конструкторе и у него будут только разрешенные методы для модификации коллекции.

Comment: А код везде ваш? В простейшем случае, если у вас в коде нету модификации коллекции, то должно быть всё равно.

Comment: @tym32167, сервис, додумался после того как создал вопрос) vm не должна же вообще логику делать

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что VM не должна логику делать? Задача VM - пережевывать данные из модели в понятный интерфейсу вид и обратно. Узконаправленные задачи можно конечно по классам (сервисам) распихать, но это не говорит о том, что логики в VM не должно быть. В UI бизнес-логики не должно быть, в модели должны быть вообще только данные, VM тоже не при делах, а как софт то писать тогда?

Comment: По поводу запрета на изменение и удаление, это точно ваше приложение? У вас злой код, который так и наровит погрызть вам данные? Методы с цепи срываются? Или появляются лишние кнопки, юзеры в них сразу же жмут, и вы хотите консистентность данных контролить во всем приложении? Вы уверены в этом? Ну заверните данные в абстракцию и дайте злому классу в конструктор аргументом, чтобы он вообще ничего не мог лишнего дернуть. Это же вроде просто должно быть. Только помните о том, сколько всего вам придется переколбасить, чтобы CRU в CRUD превратить, или наоборот. Отсюда и плясать.

Comment: @aepot бизнес по сервисам а vm только конект с видом

Comment: Каждый сам творит свой код. Главное - не впадать в 2 крайности: 1) беспредел и мешанина, 2) паттерн или смерть. Паттерны помогают писать код правильно, но не всегда, и опытный программист должен чувствовать, когда это "не всегда" наступает. Именно такие разработчики, которые могут творить адекватный (быстрый, поддерживаемый, расширяемый) код вне паттернов, эти самые паттерны и придумывают. Вот и вам успехов в этом нелегком, но прекрасном труде.